# Persistent message every time explorer process is started

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, boot

Every time the explorer process is opened i get a dialog box that pops up saying that windows cannot find a folder:

[image]

This happens every time I log in or manually restart the explorer process. I've already checked the startup programs through task manager and the *%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup* folder.

I'm thinking there may be another place in the registry i can check? I also tried making a folder on the C drive named programs and this folder opens up every time the explorer process gets restarted with no error. So there is a setting somewhere telling explorer to open the folder *C:\programs* on start up (whether its there or not) and i just cant find out where.

It's not harmful, just strange and very annoying. Thanks in advance.

I'm on Windows 8.1 if that helps

Comment: In CCleaner; go to Tools -> Startup, then click "Save to text file" and paste the contents of that text file in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

One of your startup programs is specified with a path that isn't surrounded by quotes but should be, so it is being split at the space in "C:\Program Files...".

You'll have to find out what it is and either remove or fix it.

You could try running e.g. [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) (both the cleaner and the registry scan), it's good about finding broken shortcuts (in the case of the start => startup folder) and other startup items. Your only choice there will be to delete it rather than fix it, but you could also see what it finds then fix it yourself instead of telling it to delete it (if you want).

Failing that (as per your comments), the other possibility is that perhaps one of your startup programs takes a file or path as a command line parameter, and that file or path is "C:\Program Files\something" but is missing the quotes, and then that program is generating the dialog box complaining about "C:\Program".

One thing you could try in this case is to grab [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). When the dialog is on the screen, run it. Click the target icon in the Process Explorer toolbar and drag it onto the dialog. It will tell you what process owns the dialog and this could give you another hint as to the offending process.

You are correct in your assessment that it is harmless, although it should not have gotten there in the first place, of course (not a problem but perhaps indicative of a bug in some installer / update / uninstaller somewhere).

Comment: I thought thats what it was too but i don't think that's right. I tried restarting in safe mode and am still getting this error. Also ive already tried ccleaner with the cleaner and registry fixer to no avail. with a quick look look through msconfig and ccleaner i didnt see any entries to programs that weren't starting up correctly. It happens anytime the explorer process is restarted, whether it be through task manager or restarting computer. Any other idea?

Comment: @TylerThomas I've updated my answer with another thought and something to try; see if you can use Process Explorer to identify the source of the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. However, this told me that the explorer process itself was generating the dialog. This is truly puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check for non-Microsoft "Shell Extensions". These are COM objects that act as extensions to Explorer (not IE, just explorer.exe... but they are analagous to IE plugins).

NirSoft has a utility for viewing them: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Sort by the company name, then disable all non-Microsoft extensions. Kill explorer and launch a new one and see if the problem is fixed. If it is, use process of elimination to see which extension is the issue.

To do a really thorough check of startup folders and run keys, use the SysInternals AutoRuns tool. But, I don't think it's that, because that stuff is only processed when you actually log in... not every time a new Explorer process starts.

Comment: not everything [Autoruns](www.sysinternals.com/autoruns.exe) displays is only run at machine startup or user logon.  For example, many items shown on the _Explorer_ tab relate to the Context menus in Windows.  The OP may want to run Autotuns and look for entries highlighted in yellow which indicate entries that point to a missing file, or in this case, a file with an invalid pathname.

Comment: Good catch. I'd forgotten about that tab in Autoruns. The Context menus in Explorer are in fact created by Shell Extensions, and shexview will show those. In fact it shows about eight times as many objects as Autoruns' Explorer tab does, as it breaks them down by individual COM objects while Autoruns shows files referenced within registry keys; each of those can export several COM objects. IME ShExView is a more efficient way of looking at them, since it lets you sort by Publisher, etc., but I don't know if it highlights missing files. (I haven't had missing ones, just broken ones!)